# Inferring types in array

Tags: typescript

Given the following:

```
type ArrayInfer<A> = A extends (infer I)[] ? I : never;

const a = ["foo", 1, {a: "foo"}];
type inferred = ArrayInfer<typeof a>;
```

My type `inferred` resolves to:

```
type inferred = string | number | {
    a: string;
}
```

But if I change my array slightly to include an empty object literal:

```
const a = ["foo", 1, {}];
```

Then `inferred` no longer includes `string` and `number` in its type definition:

```
type inferred = {}
```

Why is that?

Comment: I think that `{}` is a common ancestor for `string` and `number`.

Comment: My first guess here is that the [best common type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type) is inferred to be `{}`, which is from a time when `{}` was considered a top type (nowadays you'd use `unknown`) and when union types didn't yet exist.  Not sure if that's official enough to put in an answer, though.

Comment: [possibly relevant Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14828)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend @Cerberus' answer and as suggested by @Paleo in the comments, all types in JavaScript except `Object.create(null)`, `null` and `undefined` have `Object` as their top ancestors as shown by the following code snippet:

```js
const arr = [{}, 1, 'hello', (a, b) => a+b, true, null, undefined, Object.create(null)];

function getPrototypeChain(value) {
  const ancestors = [];
  let proto = value;
  while (proto) {
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
    if (proto) {
      ancestors.push(proto.constructor.name);
    }
  };
  return ancestors
}

arr.forEach(x => console.log(x, '->', getPrototypeChain(x).join(' -> ')));
```

From the TypeScript doc ([Best Common Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type), suggested by @jcalz in the comments):

> When a type inference is made from several expressions, the types of those expressions are used to calculate a “best common type”.
>   [...]
>   The best common type algorithm considers each candidate type, and picks the type that is compatible with all the other candidates.

So if you use a non-empty object, no best common type will be found in the list, and since

> When no best common type is found, the resulting inference is the union array type

You get a union of all item types as the result.

However, from the moment you include a single empty object in your list and you don't have any `null` or `undefined` items, `Object` becomes the best common type and the output will be an empty object.

Comment: Of course, there is `Object.create(null)`, but except that - thanks for extending! It's really better then what I could construct myself.

Comment: Thank you @Cerberus, I added `Object.create(null)` this to the list as well :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that both `string` and `number` are assignable to `{}`: [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20arr%3A%20%7B%7D%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B''%2C%200%5D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20item%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0Aconst%20item2%3A%20%7B%7D%20%3D%200%3B) (in fact, every type would be assignable to `{}`, except `null`, `void` and `undefined`). So TypeScript unifies three types to the widest one. When you had the first case, there wasn't one type to use among the three ones presented, so you've had a union.

Comment: So would it be expected that `const a3 = ["foo", 1, {}, undefined];` produce anything other than `type inferred3 = {}`?

Comment: @MisterEpic with `--strictNullChecks` enabled, yes (should be `{} | undefined`)